# How to visit custom numpy datatype array's member as an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-dtype

I was trying to implement my custom quaternion datatype which has 4 members: w, x, y, z.
And I found the official example code: 
https://github.com/numpy/numpy-dtypes/tree/master/npytypes/quaternion

I tested this implementation by following:

```
import numpy as np
import npytypes.quaternion

a = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=np.float).astype(np.quaternion)
print(a)
print(a[0][0].w) # correct, get 0.0
print(a.w) # wrong, AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'w'
```

And I got:

```
[[quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0) quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0)]
 [quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0) quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0)]]
0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/..../test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(a.w)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'w'
```

What I expect was like:

```
>>> a.w
array([[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]], dtype=np.float)
```

And my question is that **how can I modify that code to achive this goal**?

`np.complex` did it well:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(2, 3).astype(np.complex)
>>> a
array([[0.94226049+0.j, 0.71994713+0.j, 0.718848  +0.j],
       [0.57285105+0.j, 0.35576711+0.j, 0.51016149+0.j]])
>>> a.real
array([[0.94226049, 0.71994713, 0.718848  ],
       [0.57285105, 0.35576711, 0.51016149]])
>>> a.real.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Comment: `np.complex` doesn't add new array attributes. `real` and `imag` are present on any numeric array.

Comment: (They're present on other arrays, too, though they might raise an error or behave weird.)

Comment: This package was developed 8 yrs ago as a one time 'sprint'.  It's not been maintained or extended, and thus shouldn't be seen as 'complete'.  Also looks like the core is `c` code, so a python user can't readily add features.  The `readme` doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 1):

You might think arrays of complex dtype have extra attributes, but that's probably because you haven't tried to access `arr.real` or `arr.imag` on an array of non-complex dtype. It works. Those attributes aren't something specific to complex dtypes - they're baseline NumPy array functionality. (Also, `np.complex` is just a backwards compatibility alias for the regular Python `complex` type - when you specify `complex` as a dtype, NumPy will automatically interpret that as requesting NumPy's complex128 dtype.)

`np.ndarray` does not have any support for what you're attempting. You could subclass `np.ndarray` if you really wanted, but that gets messy and wouldn't help with regular arrays.

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried accessing ``arr.real`` on an regular dtype array, it really works! Is it doable to write something like  ``arr.w()`` to access the w matrix using the Numpy-C API? And write ``arr.add_w(arr)`` to add something to it. I have to write custom operators and I guess subclass may not work (not for sure). Or if there is a way to combine them together